# Modifications in default document won't take effect

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We have a website developed by ASP.NET+IIS7 and its default document is default.aspx. It works fine. But when we tried to switch the default to index.html, weird things happened.

We have modified web.config as follows: 
   `<defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>`

and we have clear everything under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files``, and restart the worker process. We even changed the name of Default.aspx to dddd.aspx.

But everything stays the same when accessing with `http://localhost/<MyAppName>/`!

And when we tried to access with `http://localhost/<MyAppName>`/index.html, it works fine.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your IIS Website Settings. The order in which the documents will be served.

**You problably have**

Default.aspx
Index.html

**It should be** 

Index.html
Default.aspx